# We have removed [remove]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remove) has 531 questions, 43 followers, and no tag wiki. An arbitrary tag that seems too broad to add value to any given post. Most of the posts tagged with [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remove) seem to be used by low-rep users.

The first five questions are about:

- Removing DOM elements in Javascript
- An arbitrary error message
- Adding a project to .gitignore *( [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remove) git tracking )*
- Deleting a document in Python
- Removing DOM elements using JQuery

###### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No.

###### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Sure, the concept of *programmatically* removing something is on-topic.

###### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No

###### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remove) + git vs [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remove) + java + array have fairly different meanings.

Comment: Additionally, C and C++ has a standard function named `remove`. I agree that this is a very ambiguous tag.

Comment: I guess [git + remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git+remove) questions could be retagged [tag:git]+[tag:git-rm]. The [tag:remove] is a *concept* of removing something from something (an action). One definitely can't be an expert at *removing* in general, same as with [tag:insert], [tag:append], etc. Looking solely at [c# + remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remove+c%23) I don't have problem with tag to stay. Does it cause the harm? I guess one can use it to narrow the search, but SO search is not a thing to consider.

Comment: New users use tags as if they were search keywords, but tags aren't really that (they happen to work as keywords only once you know what tag you need, but that requires research a-priori, not randomly typing something in like into Google).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Please, remove this awful tag. It covers language ranging from Bash scripting to Swift to JavaScript to CSS to Perl to Python to R to VBA to ExtendScript and topics ranging from collection manipulation to string manipulation to uninstallation to regular expressions, so it's of very little use for identifying the actual topic of questions. It's *highly* unlikely that any one person actually knows about all of those languages, so I really don't see what this is contributing in terms of helping people find questions that they're interested in.

A few example tags that this can be replaced with (*not* comprehensive)

- [uninstallation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uninstallation) for removal of programs
- [string-manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-manipulation) (synonym of [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string)) for questions about string manipulation
- [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays) or [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) for questions about collection manipulation

Comment: By considering this logic that this tag covers literally every programming language then `arrays` should be removed too, I agree it's a very broad and ambiguous tag but I think your logic is not fair.

Comment: @YaMiN Arrays are a language-independent data structure, though. "Remove", however, is... I don't know.

Comment: @YaMiN arrays at least is a established programming concept, remove is just a verb.

Comment: @YaMiN The problem isn't that it's a tag that can be used across programming languages, but it's a tag that can't stand on its own. Remove is ambiguous and uninformative. While grouping posts that deal with arrays, lists, and strings can be useful, grouping posts by whether or not they involve removing something isn't productive

Comment: Related: **[tag:removeall]**: 293 questions.  Tag help says *Issues regarding using removeAll method in Java's Collection class* which is clear and unambiguous (if maybe too specific too warrant a tag) but searching for [`[removeall] -[java]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/removeall+-java) returns 210 questions.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the "applies in many languages" observation is relevant. The pertinent issue here is that "removing something" is not a strong enough semantic concept around which a body of knowledge can be compiled, unlike particular data structures (such as arrays) or functions etc. "Removing" might entail actual taggable concepts like reference tracking, linked-list manipulation etc, but the concept as it stands is too broad.

Answer (score 15):

[remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remove) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

In most instances, this tag is a Meta tag and can merely be removed

## Progress:

The [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remove) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=remove),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bremove%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bremove%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bremove%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bremove%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of burnination](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=408573)

Rodgort's burnination progress chart (this is updated from time-to-time; see burnination chat room for the most recent)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remove) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remove) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remove) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.