# Let's [remove] it once and for all

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blocklist-request

The [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remove) tag has been [burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408573/10871900) last year.

I saw that it reappeared and new questions were tagged with it.

Hence, I suggest to blocklist it with the following error message:

> Tagging a question with [remove] does not add any value to questions. Consider using tags like [uninstallation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uninstallation) for removal of programs, [string-manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-manipulation) for questions about string manipulation, [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays)/[list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) for questions about collection manipulation or similar tags.

Comment: on the bright side, not a stuck tag for once

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to our good friend Adam, this is now blocked with Mr Developer's recommended text.

[image: Red text warning that the remove tag is not allowed - "The remove tag has been blocked permanently from Stack Overflow, as it does not add any value to questions. Consider using tags like uninstallation for removal of programs, string-manipulation for questions about string manipulation, arrays/list for questions about collection manipulation or similar tags."]

Answer (score 7):

I agree. It seems as though people keep adding this tag back - as of right now, it seems as though there are no questions tagged with [remove]. However, what if we changed the the first sentence of the error to the following:

> The [remove] tag has been blocked permanently from Stack Overflow, as it does not add any value to questions.

So the full error message would be:

> The [remove] tag has been blocked permanently from Stack Overflow, as it does not add any value to questions. Consider using tags like [uninstallation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uninstallation) for removal of programs, [string-manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-manipulation) for questions about string manipulation, [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays)/[list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) for questions about collection manipulation or similar tags.